# Whats going on with the ChromeOS tag?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Unix & Linux Stack Exchange post: [Native Packet Dropping on ChromeOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629329/native-packet-dropping-on-chromeos)

I've been having a look at the ChromeOS tag and it seems to be doing poorly. Questions are rarely answered and asked (the last answered question was July 2020). Is there a better place to answer these type of questions?

Comment: Here's a link to the tag: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-os